# calculate the limit $b_{n}=\sqrt[n]{2^{n}+3^{n}+4^{n}}$

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, limits

Can somebody help me and explain this limit? 
$$b_{n}=\sqrt[n]{2^{n}+3^{n}+4^{n}}$$ $$\lim_{n \to \infty} b_n=?$$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$$4\leq \sqrt[n]{2^n+3^n+4^n}\leq4\sqrt[n]{3}$$ now just squeeze.

Comment: how do we know that $\sqrt[n]{2^n+3^n+4^n}\leq4\sqrt[n]{3}$ ?

Comment: @DimitrisPapapdimitriou Replace all terms with the largest, $4^n$.

Answer (score 3):

Hint:

$$b_{n}=4\times \sqrt[n]{\left(\frac12\right)^{n}+\left(\frac34\right)^{n}+1}$$

Comment: I thought this was a good first move also. But what to do with the root ? In the end you have to use squeeze, for that, so that the first move here is not so essential.

Comment: what is that "\left(1+ \frac2{n})^n \ge 3" i dont understand it

Comment: @ReneSchipperus the next step could be to say that the root is above 1 and below $\sqrt[n] 3 \le 1+\frac2n \to 1$

Comment: Yes, I know, but that makes the first factorization step irrelevant.

Answer (score 0):

Dealing with $\log$, we have $n^{-1}\log(2^{n}+3^{n}+4^{n})>n^{-1}\log 4^{n}=\log 4$ for all $n$. Now find $N$ such that $2^{n}+3^{n}+4^{n}=4^{n}(2^{-n}+(3/4)^{n}+1)<2\cdot 4^{n}$ for all $n\geq N$, then $\log 4\leq\log b_{n}\leq\log 4+n^{-1}\log 2$, so $\lim_{n}\log b_{n}=\log 4$.

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming that you want $\displaystyle \lim_{n\to\infty} b_n$. Call it $\beta$.

$$\beta=\lim_{n\to\infty} \sqrt[n]{2^n+3^n+4^n}$$
$$\ln(\beta)=\lim_{n\to\infty} \frac{\ln\left(2^n+3^n+4^n\right)}{n}$$
$$\ln(\beta)=\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{2^n\ln(2)+3^n\ln(3)+4^n\ln(4)}{2^n+3^n+4^n}$$
$$\ln(\beta)=\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{2^{-n}\ln(2)+\left(\frac{3}{4}\right)^n\ln(3)+\ln(4)}{2^{-n}+\left(\frac{3}{4}\right)^n+1}$$
$$ln(\beta)=\ln(4)\rightarrow \beta=4$$
So
$$\lim_{n\to\infty} b_n=4$$
The interchange of limit and function composition is justified because of continuity.

Comment: How do you get from the second line to the third?

Comment: I applied L'Hopital's rule, differentiating both the numerator and the denominator.